# How do I show the last created node in a block, without using Views?

Tags: nodes

How do I show the last created node in a block, without using the Views module?

Comment: why wouldn't you want to use views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way would be to create a custom module that will find/load the node and display in a block. Assuming Drupal 6 from your previous questions.

In your custom module:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_block()
 */
function YOURMODULE_block($op='list', $delta=0, $edit=array()) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'list':
      $blocks[0]['info'] = t('Last Node Created');
      return $blocks;

    case 'view':
      // Get the last created node
      $nid = db_result(db_query('SELECT MAX(nid) AS nid FROM {node}'));
      $node = node_load($nid);

      // Add subject/content to block
      $blocks['subject'] = t('Last Node Created');
      $blocks['content'] = theme('YOURMODULE_node_last', $node);
      return $blocks;
  }
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme()
 */
function YOURMODULE_theme() {
  return array(
    'YOURMODULE_node_last' => array(
      'arguments' => array('node' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Create the HTML output for last created node
 *
 * @param $node
 * Node object for last created node
 */
function theme_YOURMODULE_node_last($node) {
  // Insert theming code here...
}
```

For more information on creating custom modules, see the [Module developer's guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules).

Comment: isn't there a simplier way to solve this task. For example in page.tpl.php i've created a div and i want to display inside that div node_load() some node, but i dont know how to get the nid of the last created node.

Comment: This way is pretty simple since most the module code is given to you already. You can do it in page.tpl.php... but it's not the way it _should_ be done.  If you are stuck on doing it that way, the database query to get the last node is in the code I posted above (look in `case 'view'`)

Comment: ok, how to make a filter by content type for example 'audio' not every node on the site :)

Comment: Just add a `WHERE` clause to the DB query: `SELECT MAX(nid) AS nid FROM {node} WHERE type = "audio"`

Comment: Thanks, and the last created node would appear in my block?

Comment: If you use my example you will have to finish the module, it is not complete (change YOURMODULE to name of your module, finish the theme function, create .info file).  If you use your way of in page.tpl.php, that query will give you the nid, which you can use in `node_load()`.

Comment: One more question - how to print cck fields in a this way? i did a print_r($mynode) and cannot get cck fields :(